# Only Add Filter / Function on Certain Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, function, if-statement

I have want to add the following code to my `functions.php` in WordPress:

```
add_filter( 'gform_submit_button_4', 'form_submit_button', 10, 2 );
function form_submit_button( $button, $form ) {
    return "<button class='button' id='gform_submit_button_{$form['id']}'>Get a Test Drive</button>";
}
```

But, I only want to apply it on certain pages, I've tried two avenues: a if statement using `is_page` & wrapping the gravity forms shortcode in a div with a class and targeting only `.class #gform_submit_button_4` so far I haven't been able to get either to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Willem

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `get_queried_object` function,

```
<?php
function form_submit_button( $button, $form ) {
    return "<button class='button' id='gform_submit_button_{$form['id']}'>Get a Test Drive</button>";
}
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
if ( $queried_object ) {
    $pageId = $queried_object->ID;
    if($pageId == 'someid') {
        add_filter( 'gform_submit_button_4', 'form_submit_button', 10, 2 );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Only replacing the `someid` with the id of the relevant page? Because I've tried that and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

In gravity form add a field of page slug with type hidden from back-end option of gravity form.

1) You can create field from back-end and assign it a value with JS

2) Gravity form give you an option to send url with form you can parse page slug from that url

`add_filter( 'gform_submit_button_4', 'form_submit_button', 10, 2 );
function form_submit_button( $button, $form ) {
    // please print $form and check you get your current page slug variable e.g $form['my_page_slug']
    // create an array that have your new button slugs e.g
    $pages_slug_array = array('about','contact-us');
    if(in_array($page_slug_arry, $form['my_page_slug'])){
        return $button = "<button class='button' id='gform_submit_button_{$form['id']}'>Get a Test Drive</button>";
    }
}`

Hope you got that

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I add a Hidden Field to the form with a Default Value of '{embed_url}', the in the code I replace 'my_page_slug' with the relevant page's slug 'the-new-hyundai-i20' ?

Comment: `$pages_slug_array = array('the-new-hyundai-i20');` I added it like this but the button disappears on both forms?